# Accounting software for a USA based small tech company

Tags: quickbooks, accounting, microsoft-money

I just registered my .com business as an LLC.
Which means I need to start paying taxes and do real accounting.

I have an MSDN license so I have access to all Microsoft software.
however it looks like they don't offer a Quickbooks style software app.

**Do they?**

I need something will a small learning curve as I only have one employee, myself, and simple expenses.
thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Intuit](http://www.intuit.com/) quickbooks and thier online payroll software. I've never used either, but they are popular. They are compatible with most tax software.

Answer (score 0):

You might still be able to download and use [Microsoft's Account Express 2009](http://www.brothersoft.com/office-accounting-express-2009-222829.html). It's no longer being developed, but it was a stable product and useful. They [stopped developing](http://www.ideawins.com/FAQsDiscontinuation.aspx) it because of tools like Intuit and even Excel Spreedsheets were found to be just as useful.

Hope this helps some, and good luck with your company.

Comment: Using software that's no longer being developed (and cant's run on win7 scares me)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that since it runs on vista that this software will run on Windows 7 also.